# Find an f(x) that fits specific critera (Polynomial Regression)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials, factorial, regression

I need a function (I don't care how messy it is) that when:

$f(1) = 1$ <--this has $1!$ different terms

$f(2) = a-b$     <--this has $2!$ different terms

$f(3) = a^2b-a^2c-b^2a+b^2c+c^2a-c^2b$ <--this has $3!$ different terms

$f(4) = a^3b^2c-a^3b^2d-a^3c^2b+a^3c^2d+a^3d^2b-a^3d^2c-b^3a^2c+b^3a^2d+b^3c^2a-b^3c^2d-b^3d^2a+b^3d^2c+c^3a^2b-c^3a^2d-c^3b^2a+c^3b^2d+c^3d^2a-c^3d^2b-d^3a^2b+d^3a^2c+d^3b^2a-d^3b^2c-d^3c^2a+d^3c^2b$ <--this has $4!$ different terms

$f(5) = a^4b^3c^2d-a^4b^3c^2e-a^4b^3d^2c+a^4b^3d^2e+a^4b^3e^2c-a^4b^3e^2d-a^4c^3b^2d+a^4c^3b^2e+a^4c^3d^2b-a^4c^3d^2e-a^4c^3e^2b+a^4c^3e^2d+a^4d^3b^2c-a^4d^3b^2e-a^4d^3c^2b+a^4d^3c^2e+a^4d^3e^2b-a^4d^3e^2c-a^4e^3b^2c+a^4e^3b^2d+a^4e^3c^2b-a^4e^3c^2d-a^4e^3d^2b+a^4e^3d^2c+b^4a^3c^2d-$ <--this would have $5!$ different terms (If I typed all 120 of them)

This function lists all of the unique combinations of the letters and the powers used. Hopefully you can see the pattern between the what is stated above, I just can't find a way to describe it.

This function would be a necessary part for working out a formula for 2-dimensional polynomial regression.

I do realize that there are multiple answers for this and any help for this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This equation works for **all** the values:

$$-\prod_{i=1}^{N-1}(-\prod_{j=1}^i(x_{i+1}-x_j))$$

Where $x =1,2,3,...,N-1,N$

and $N =$ length of sequence $x$

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be
$$
\eqalign{
  & f\left( n \right) = \sum\limits_{\left\{ {j_1 , \cdots ,j_n } \right\} \in S\;even} {\left( {x_{\,j_{\,1} }  - x_{\,j_{\,2} } } \right)x_{\,j_{\,3} } ^2 x_{\,j_{\,4} } ^3  \cdots x_{\,j_{\,n} } ^{n - 1} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left\{ {j_1 , \cdots ,j_n } \right\} \in S\;even} {\left( {x_{\,j_{\,1} }  - x_{\,j_{\,2} } } \right)\prod\limits_{3\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {x_{\,j_{\,k} } ^{k - 1} } } \quad |\;2 \le n  \cr} 
$$
where $S\, \text{even}$ denotes the set of the permutations of $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$
[which are even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation) (even number of inversions).

That is, we denote $a,b,c, ...$ as $x_1,x_2,..$.
Then for example, in the case of $n=3$ we have $3!$ permutations, half of which are even and half odd. So the expression above becomes

[image: Prod_permut_1]

Comment: Whilst I understand the product function part, I don't know what varible the sum function is summing between. I only have a light understanding of permutations, but as far as I can tell "{j1,...,jn}€S even" is a constant.

Comment: @M.P.Tree: It is standard to denote the range of a sum as the set of all the $n$-uples which the indices can take. In this case it is meant to say that the $n$-uple $(j_1,\cdots,j_n)$ can take all the values corresponding to an even permutation of the base $n$-uple $(1,2,\cdots,n)$. I added an example that may clear that: let me know if you have further doubts.

Comment: @G Cab This equation works when n = 3 but for n = 4 it gives a negative version of the answer and for n = 5 the answer is off considerably. To work it out I used x = (1, 2, 3) and it gives -2 as the answer which is correct; then I used x = (1, 2, 3, 4) and it gave -12 when the answer should have been 12. Finally I used  x = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and it gave -288 instead of 20775. The pattern cannot be written as sum((xj1-xj2)*xj3^2*xj4^3*...) but instead written as (sum ((sum ((xj1-xj2)*xj3^2))*xj4^3))*xj5^4... this would have n - 3 sum functions inside of oneanother which I don't know how to write

Comment: @M.P.Tree: in fact, I started with **"Seems to be.."**. Now, the formula I suggested is right for $n=2,3$, while for $n=4$ the sign is reverted. To be able and (maybe) provide further help, you shall make known the algorithm/criteria/formula with which you generate the sequences.